# Is it possible to insert Child record before it's parent record in ORACLE 11g?

Tags: oracle

I need to write a DML script that will show how it is 
possible to INSERT a CHILD RECORD before its PARENT RECORD, if the child's FK constraint checking is
delayed until save time and need to 
manually perform the change that will allow this check delay.

Below are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
       cust_code    VARCHAR2(3),
       name         VARCHAR2(50),
      region        VARCHAR2(5))
TABLESPACE  mine;

CREATE TABLE orders (
      ord_id        NUMBER(3),
      ord_date      DATE,
      cust_code     VARCHAR2(3),
      date_of_dely  DATE )
TABLESPACE  mine
PCTFREE     20
PCTUSED     50
MAXTRANS    100;
```

`Primary Key` in `Customer` is `cust_code`
`Foreign Key` in `Orders` is `cust_code`

Comment: There is no primary key in `customer` - read your CREATE TABLE statement again and show us where you see a primary key. (If you created it separately, **SHOW** that code too!) More importantly, show how you defined the foreign key in `orders`. If the constraint is deferred, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete, working example. Notice the referential integrity constraint (the foreign key constraint) in `orders` - it is `deferrable initially deferred`.

```
create table customers (
  cust_code    varchar2(3)  primary key
, name         varchar2(50)
, region       varchar2(5)
)
;

Table CUSTOMERS created.

create table orders (
  ord_id       number(3)
, ord_date     date
, cust_code    varchar2(3)  references customers(cust_code) deferrable initially deferred
, date_of_dely date
)
;

Table ORDERS created.


insert into orders values (101, sysdate, 'AAA', sysdate + 7);

1 row inserted.

insert into customers values ('AAA', 'Some Name', 'MyReg');

1 row inserted.


commit;

Commit complete.
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to create two costraints (primary key+foreing key) in order to utilize child/parent relationship checking:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
       cust_code    VARCHAR2(3),
       name         VARCHAR2(50),
      region        VARCHAR2(5),
      constraint cust_pk PRIMARY KEY ( cust_code)
);


CREATE TABLE orders (
      ord_id        NUMBER(3),
      ord_date      DATE,
      cust_code     VARCHAR2(3),
      date_of_dely  DATE,
      constraint cust_fk foreign key (cust_code) references customers(cust_code) deferrable
      )
;
```

Notice keyword **deferrable** at the end of the constraint definition. This makes the constraint deferrable, that is constraint checking can be deferred, without this clause it is not possible.

---

Now if you try to insert an order referencing to not existing customer you will get an error, because the order must be inserted beforehand:

```
insert into orders values( 1, sysdate, 1, sysdate);

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST.CUST_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

---

But you can use [SET CONSTRAINT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10003.htm#SQLRF01703) command to change this behaviour and deferre constraints checking for single transaction until commit, thus you can insert the order without customer, the checking of constraint will be deferred until commit time:

```
set constraint cust_fk deferred;
Constraint CUST_FK succeeded.

insert into orders values( 1, sysdate, 1, sysdate);
1 row inserted.

commit;
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST.CUST_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

Comment: Make the constraint `deferrable initially deferred` - why do you need an additional step?

Comment: Also, it would help the OP if in your last piece of code you demonstrated inserting into the child first (succeeded), then inserting into the parent, and then `commit` successfully, since the referential constraint is only checked at commit time. What you show is correct, but doesn't quite answer the OP's question.